# R function mistake

Tags: r, func

I have the function and mistake:
"Error in `vectbl_as_row_location()`:
! Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 140121 but subscript `data$pole == "(-Inf,20]"` has size 0.
How to solve it?

```
func<-function(data,pole){
  
  data[data$pole=='(-Inf,20]',]$pole <- '(-Inf,25]'
  data[data$pole=='(20,25]',]$pole <- '(-Inf,25]'
  
  data[data$pole=='(25,30]',]$pole <- '(25,35]'
  data[data$pole=='(30,35]',]$pole <- '(25,35]'
  
  data[data$pole=='(35,40]',]$pole <- '(35,45]'
  data[data$pole=='(40,45]',]$pole <- '(35,45]'
  
  data[data$pole=='(45,50]',]$pole <- '(45,Inf]'
  data[data$pole=='(50,55]',]$pole <- '(45,Inf]'
  data[data$pole=='(55,60]',]$pole <- '(45,Inf]'
  data[data$pole=='(60,65]',]$pole <- '(45,Inf]'
  data[data$pole=='(65, Inf]',]$pole <- '(45,Inf]'
  
  
}

func(answers_clean$dem,dem_answer)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It looks like the function is expecting a data frame, but you're passing it a vector (ie a single column from your data frame).  If you've got some complicated nested data frame, then you'd best post a sample with `dput`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to combine factor levels. Here is an example using data that is available in R:

```
data(iris)
SL <- iris$Sepal.Length
SL.cut <- cut(SL, breaks=8)
table(SL.cut)
SL.cut
# (4.3,4.75] (4.75,5.2] (5.2,5.65] (5.65,6.1] (6.1,6.55]   (6.55,7]   (7,7.45] (7.45,7.9] 
#         11         34         20         30         25         18          6          6
```

Now combine adjacent levels so we have 4 groups instead of 8:

```
SL.cut2 <- SL.cut
levels(SL.cut2) <- c("(4.3, 5.2]", "(4.3, 5.2]", "(5.2, 6.1]", "(5.2, 6.1]", "(6.1, 7]", "(6.1, 7]", "(7, 7.9]", "(7, 7.9]")
table(SL.cut2)
SL.cut2
# (4.3, 5.2] (5.2, 6.1]   (6.1, 7]   (7, 7.9] 
#         45         50         43         12
```